# Is $\exists x[p(x)\to ¬ q(x)]$ equivalent to $\exists xp(x)\to\exists x ¬q(x).$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have to show that $\exists x[p(x)\to ¬ q(x)]$  is not equivalent to $\exists xp(x)\to\exists x ¬q(x)$.

Using well-known equivalences, it seems impossible to prove that the two formulas are equivalent.

But how can I prove that the two formulas are not equivalent? any idea? I tried several examples and I am stuck.

Comment: On the other hand $\exists x[p(x)\to\lnot q(x)]$ is equivalent to $\forall xp(x)\to\exists x\lnot q(x)$.

Comment: It is easy to see it is false. Write the implication inside the quantification using disjunction. Note that Existential Quantifier Distributes over Disjunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formulas are not equivalent. Consider a domain with exactly two elements, $0$ and $1$. For $0$, both properties $p$ and $q$ hold. For $1$, the property $p$ is false but the property $q$ holds.

Thus, with this interpretation, the formula $\exists x p(x)$ is true (because of $0$) but $\exists x \lnot q(x)$ is false (since $q$ holds for both elements of our domain). Hence, $\exists x p(x) \to \exists x \lnot q(x)$ is false.

According to this interpretation, for $x = 1$, $p(x) \to \lnot q(x)$ is true (since $p$ is false for $1$), so $\exists x (p(x) \to \lnot q(x))$ is true.

We have shown that there exists a domain and an interpretation of the predicates $p$ and $q$ such that the formulas $\exists x p(x) \to \exists x \lnot q(x)$ and $\exists x (p(x) \to \lnot q(x))$ do not have the same truth value. Therefore, the two formulas are not equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much, i spent all day thinking how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

We know theorem
$$(\exists x) (R \lor S) \Leftrightarrow \big((\exists x)R \lor (\exists x)S \big)$$
Now is enough to remember, that $A \Rightarrow B$ is same as $\neg A \lor B$.
So we can write:
$$(\exists x) (R \Rightarrow S) \Leftrightarrow \big((\exists x)\neg R \lor (\exists x)S \big) \quad (1)$$

From another hand
$$(\exists x)\neg R  \Rightarrow (\exists x)S \Leftrightarrow  \big((\forall x)\neg  R \lor (\exists x)S \big) \quad (2)$$
As we see $(1)$ and $(2)$ have essential difference in right hand in quantifiers.

Comment: I get this. But i have problems with the proof of the statement. What do you mean?

Comment: Denote by "$A=p(x)$" and "$B=\neg q(x)$" and you will get your statement.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco. Nicolas Bourbaki - Theory of sets(1968) page 39. If you prefer more new book it also is not problem. As to your answer, that let little time to think about.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the two formulas are equivalent? They aren't. Your answer actually means that $\exists x (R \lor S) \iff (\forall x \lnot R) \lor (\exists x S)$, or that $\exists x (R \to S) \iff (\exists x \lnot R) \lor (\exists x S)$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco. Firstly: in last comment You use $\forall$ after first equivalence - possible typo/mistake?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the first equivalence I wrote, but it is not the universal quantifier. What I wanted to say is: "Your answer actually means that $∃x(R∨S) ⟺ (∀x¬R)\to (∃xS)$, or that $∃x(R→S)⟺(∃x¬R)∨(∃xS)$".

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco. Sorry, but there is again $\forall$ in your last comment. Again typo or it is intentionally? And we can move to chat, if you agree, to avoid discussing in comments as usually here is suggested.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco. Now about your answer:  You manipulate with $\exists x p(x) \to \exists x \lnot q(x)$, but this is $\forall x p(x) \lor \exists x \lnot q(x)$, so is not same as I wrote. My answer is true and not contradicts with yours and not claims what you saw in it in first statement from your comments.  And of course it is true that $\exists x (R \to S) \iff (\exists x \lnot R) \lor (\exists x S)$.

Comment: @Gabriel. I wrote in detail what I mean and to assure you, that way indicated in first version in my answer is correct - now it is fully written.